# Запрос post из php

Tags: post, php, get

Я хочу отправить массив пост на http://evergreens.bitrix24.ru/crm/configs/import/lead.php

По документации запросы могут быть как get так и пост.
через ajax jquery все нормально отправляется, и лиды добавляются из формы. Но я хочу чтобы логин и пароль были скрытыми, поэтому пишу php класс. Вот та часть кода которая отвечает за отправку данных методом post

```
$options = array('http' => array(
                    'method' => 'GET',
                    'header' => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' . PHP_EOL,
                    'content' => $postData
                ));

$url = 'http://evergreens.bitrix24.ru/crm/configs/import/lead.php';
$context = stream_context_create($options);
$result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
```

В результате получаю ошибку, 
{'error':'400','error_message':'Ошибка запроса'}
такую же как если бы вобще не отправлять никаких данных.
 Я подразумеваю что данные должны находиться ИМЕННО в массиве $_POST а не передаваться в качестве контента. Возможно я и заблуждаюсь.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Так content кладет ваш postData в тело запроса, а сервер получая GET запрос ожидает параметры из урла.

То есть надо прилепить к урлу кодированную строчку

Если postData у вас массив, то так должно выглядеть

```
$query = http_build_query($postData);
$url = 'http://evergreens.bitrix24.ru/crm/configs/import/lead.php?'.$query;
$result = file_get_contents($url);
```

Comment: Отлично! спасибо, так все работает

Comment: @Nikolas Mikhno, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).